# Angle of phone rotated along X axis

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am working on an Android app wherein I want to scroll a large image horizontally. I used the accelerometer (Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) and magnetic field (Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) data to get the angle of rotation. This data being to frequent infested with noise I am not able to implement a smooth motion effect.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            mags = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accels = event.values.clone();
            break;
    }

    if (mags != null && accels != null) {
        gravity = new float[16];
        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(gravity, null, accels, mags);
        if (success) {
            float[] outGravity = new float[16];
            SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(gravity, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outGravity);
            SensorManager.getOrientation(outGravity, values);

            rollingAverage[0] = roll(rollingAverage[0], values[0]);
            rollingAverage[1] = roll(rollingAverage[1], values[1]);
            rollingAverage[2] = roll(rollingAverage[2], values[2]);

            azimuth = Math.toDegrees(values[0]);
            pitch = Math.toDegrees(values[1]);
            roll = Math.toDegrees(values[2]);
            mags = null;
            accels = null;

            double diffRoll = lastRoll - roll;
            double diffPitch = lastPitch - pitch;
            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (Math.abs(diffRoll) >= 2) {
                if (diffRoll > 0)
                    imageView.panLeft();
                else
                    imageView.panRight();
                lastRoll = roll;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on achieving this using other methods?

Comment: Accelerometer is a noisy sensor.  Unless you do some DSP algorithms to filter/smooth it, you will jump all over the place.  Looks like you're trying to do this with the roll() function, but we'd need to see it to know what you're already doing.

Comment: How is this achieved in motion games or VR?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement sensor fusion techniques based on Kalman filter or other filters. You can use open source libraries if needed. Refer this [bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src/caa492f9659e/app/src/?at=master). If you want to do yourself, read the [tutorial.](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/729759/android-sensor-fusion-tutorial)

Comment: Thanks! Check the Sensor fusion demo app and the accelerometer + compass solution also shows a shaky cube.